# Limit on maximum event polling in libuv

Tags: node.js, libuv

I am checking nodejs internals and is exploring libuv library. In that, there's a method uv__io_poll in which it poll for IO events. The code is bit hard to understand, so please forgive if the question is naive.

In the code(kqueue.c), the first line is
`struct kevent events[1024];`

I wanted to know that is there any upper limit of events we can listen at a given time.
Suppose I have node code that calls DB and is firing 3-4k read promises parallelly. Will libuv listen to only 1024 events in a cycle or can it listen to all of them?